# Image comparison with kaze

Tags: c++, computer-vision, opencv3.0

The Photos taken from the mobile phone from a running videos are generally comes little blur and low(or high) brightness, How can i able to reduce noise of such images and what is the best way to compare such Images ?

Comment: So do you want to sharpen them, change the brightness or reduce noise? Those are three different things.

Comment: It depends how am taking picture , but for different scenarios i need all three.